# How to create a loop that asks a new random addition question after answering the previous question

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on creating a small 5 question addition quiz that asks the user a new random addition question every time they answer the previous one. I would like to be able to have my script ask a new question every time the user clicks on the "check answer" button without having to refresh the page. Then, once the user has completed the 5 questions, I would like to be able to have a popup state they have completed the quiz and can refresh the page to start a new quiz. With my current code, the script asks a random addition question, and then once the user clicks on the "check answer" button, the user must refresh the page to get a new question. I am stuck on figuring out how to modify my current code to fit what I am trying to do. I am thinking that a while loop may be they way to go, but I don't really know how to implement it. The code that I have so far is: `

```html
<h1>Addition Quiz!</h1>
<p>This short 5 question quiz will test your addition skills! Answer the question as the computer asks it and pat yourself on the back for each correct answer!</p>
<h3 id="mathquestion"></h3>
<input type="text" name="answerbox" id="answerbox">

<button onclick="addition()">Check Answer</button>

<script>
  var minimum = 1;
  var maximum = 9;
var intiger1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
var intiger2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
document.getElementById("mathquestion").innerHTML = intiger1 + " " + "+" + " " + intiger2;
var questionanswer = intiger1 + intiger2;

  function addition() {
var useranswer = document.getElementById('answerbox').value;
    if (useranswer == questionanswer) {
      alert("Correct! Congrats!");

    } else {
      alert("Sorry, your answer is incorrect. Better luck with the next question!")
    }
  }

</script>`
```

Comment: You can add your question's code snippets using with ctrl+m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want is the part that setups your question into a new function. And run that function when the answer is right. An example:

```
<script>
    var minimum = 1;
    var maximum = 9;
    var questionanswer = 0;

    setupQuestion();


function setupQuestion(){
    var intiger1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
    var intiger2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
    document.getElementById("mathquestion").innerHTML = intiger1 + " " + "+" + " " + intiger2;
    questionanswer = intiger1 + intiger2;
}


function addition() {
    var useranswer = document.getElementById('answerbox').value;
      if (useranswer == questionanswer) {
        alert("Correct! Congrats!");
        setupQuestion();
        
      } else {
        alert("Sorry, your answer is incorrect. Better luck with the next question!")
      }
    }
    
  </script>`
```

Comment: I created the setupQuestion function and set it up to run regardless if the user got the answer correct or not. I am still struggling with understanding how to create a loop that will run this script for a maximum of 5 times before giving the user an alert message that they have completed the quiz and can refresh the page to start a new quiz. What kind of loop would be best to make this happen, and how would it be implemented?

Comment: You need 1 extra variable outside the function with. questioncount = 0. Then, when someone answers it right do a `questionscount += 1`. Next add an if statement when someone answers it right. `if(questionscount === 5)` do something.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the variable

```
<script>
var minimum = 1;
var maximum = 9;
var intiger1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
var intiger2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
document.getElementById("mathquestion").innerHTML = intiger1 + " " + "+" + " " + intiger2;
var questionanswer = intiger1 + intiger2;

function addition() {
    var useranswer = document.getElementById('answerbox').value;
    if (useranswer == questionanswer) {
        alert("Correct! Congrats!");
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, your answer is incorrect. Better luck with the next question!")
    }
    
    // Updating question
    intiger1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
    intiger2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
    document.getElementById("mathquestion").innerHTML = intiger1 + " " + "+" + " " + intiger2;
}

</script>
```